# Merge multiple geo-referenced *,jpg files into a GeoTIFF in QGIS

Tags: geotiff-tiff, mosaic, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have a set of georeferenced *.jpg files from a UAV flight and want to merge them into a GeoTIFF Mosaic. Is it possible in QGIS ?

Comment: You can combine them using https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_miscellaneous/buildvirtualraster.html. It wont be orthorectified though

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible in QGIS.  The georeferenced images will contain x, y, and z values embedded in the EXIF tags of the images.  While there are several options for adding those images to QGIS you would viewing the location of the camera at capture time.  Additionally, the image would be oriented with the top edge of the camera pointing north (although there are plugins to display the image rotated based on the azimuth value in the EXIF).

You are looking for structure from motion (SfM) photogrammetry software. SfM software will exploit the EXIF data, determine image adjacency, and stitch images together to produce a single orthorectified image.   A free and opensource option would be [Open Drone Map](https://opendronemap.org/) (or WebODM) depending on your OS.  WebODM is installed via Docker so there is a bit of a technical challenge to get things up and running.  I believe there is an Ubuntu repository for ODM.

Some commercial SfM softwares are Agisoft Photoscan, Drone Deploy, and Pix4D.  These three options offer a free trial version that will get you 30 days to accomplish your task.